# Trigger OS shell script post kubernetes container boot

Tags: linux, kubernetes, shell, containers, truenas

I am running truenas scale 23.01 with kubernetes. On the system I have a container X and a small app Y running natively that interacts with this container through its local IP and port.

Whenever container X get restarted (update, OS reboot) the process of app Y gets killed and does not restart automatically.

Currently my workaround for this is to trigger a cron-job daily after my container update time. This kind of works but cron jobs are not really supposed to be used for always running services and it shows an ugly always running job in my GUI.

Is there a way I can detect that container X gets launched and then run a shell command to trigger app Y in the background? To be clear I don't want to execute a command in the container but in the Truenas Scale (linux) shell.

Alternatively, is there a version of a "cron-job" but for persistent background processes that I can still schedule?

Comment: Can you clarify something: does "app Y" run *inside * "container X"? Or it's running in a separate pod? Can you show your existing cron-job based solution? That would help make things more clear.